# Работа pyperclip.waitForNewPaste

Tags: python

Не понимаю как работает `pyperclip.waitForNewPaste`. Ниже пример самого простого кода. Первый скопированный текст выводится, второй нет, третий выводится, четвертый нет, и так далее.
Какая-то программная работа с буфером обмена ничего не дает, то есть, если добавить `clipboard.clear()` или `pyperclip.copy('lol')` вообще ничего не меняют, всё выводится так же — первый скопированный текст выводится второй нет.
Пробовал асинхронный метод, результат точно такой же. Кто знает в чём причина? Как это вообще должно работать, по `waitForNewPaste` вообще информации крайне мало.
Проверил сейчас на линукс и там всё работает верно, а под вин всё так как я описал, ну и в чём дело?

```
while True:
   print(pyperclip.waitForNewPaste())
```

Comment: pyperclip.waitForNewPaste(timeout=None): Ожидает, что новый текст будет скопирован в буфер обмена, и возвращает его в виде строки. Эта функция блокируется до тех пор, пока не будет обнаружен новый текст или пока не будет достигнут необязательный параметр тайм-аута ( в секундах ).

Comment: https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/blob/master/src/pyperclip/__init__.py#L717

Comment: Проверил. Python 3.10.7. Запустил под вин, сработал нормально.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Причину нашел вот она - import clipboard, pyperclip. Вот эти двое вместе не могут работать. Если импортировать только одну библиотеку всё работает нормально.